# How do I view all messages posted by me in particular chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I want to view all the messages posted by me in the "Ask Ubuntu General Room".

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible.

While there is a rather encompassing [chat search function](http://chat.stackexchange.com/search) which can filter by user and room, it does not have wildcards - you will have to search for *some proper query*.

That said, if you have some patience and time to dig, you can of course always go through [the full transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201).

Answer (score 0):

You can view your 20-something most recent comments in a room here:

> http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/96785/avinash-raj?tab=recent

There's a header on the left side (saying "Ask Ubuntu General Room"). Everything from that point on until the next header was in the "Ask Ubuntu General Room".